# MongoDB: Select document from a list of documents based on criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of `chats`. Each `chat` has a list (an array) of `members`. And each `member` has two fields: `user_id` and `rank` (both integers). Given `chat_id` and `user_id`, I need to get **rank** of the specified member in the given chat. What should my query look like?

**Example:**

Given database contents:

```json
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f84ffad51d91fa6247b17e6"
  },
  "chat_id": 1,
  "status": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "user_id": 178291450,
      "rank": 1
    },
    {
      "user_id": 618121637,
      "rank": 0
    }
  ]
}]
```

I want to get the `rank` of user with `user_id: 178291450` in the chat with `chat_id: 1` (should be `1`).

I have tried this:

```js
chats.find({ "chat_id": event.chat_id, "members.user_id": int(admin) }, { _id: 0, members: { $elemMatch: { "members.user_id": int(admin) } } })
```

*(from my Python code, where `event.chat_id` is the needed `chat_id`, and `admin` is equal to `178291450`),*
but this does not return anything (`{}`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB filter nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306166/mongodb-filter-nested-array)

Comment: @AlexisG it does, but I managed to find a much easier and shorter solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my initial query (from the question) a bit and this works:

```js
db.chats.find({"chat_id": 1}, {"_id" : 0, "members" : {"$elemMatch" : {"user_id" : {"$eq" : 618121637}}}})
```

*(`1` and `618121637` are sample IDs)*

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. Project rank of matched user id only.

```
chats.find({ "chat_id": event.chat_id, "members.user_id": int(admin) }, { _id: 0,  "members.$.rank"})
```

Comment: This syntax seems to be invalid in MongoDB 4.4.